# How can I combine frozen column and variable table height in Tabulator?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I would like to combine 2 features in my Tabulator table:

- frozen first column ( `{frozen:true`} in column definition)
- `max-height` CSS property of the table in `vh` (viewport height) units. (I do this in order to limit the max height of the table. If I use the fixed height property, I would have a table with lot of empty space if it had just a few rows). I use for example:

  - HTML `<div id='tabulator' class="tabulator-max-vh-50"></div>`
  - CSS `.tabulator-max-vh-50 .tabulator-tableHolder { max-height: 50vh; }`

See a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dannyvop/3fkeam7y).
There are two example tables:

1) Table with height property in Tabulator options

- fixed height
- the frozen column are really frozen when scrolling table to the right

2) Table without height property in Tabulator options
- For this table I use the CSS `max-height`
- when I scroll to the right, the frozen column [moves for a fraction of a second](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eotfKGhFEpM) and then redraws correctly, but this behavior doesn't look nice visually.

Is there any way for combining both features?

#### Edit:

My workaround at the moment is to set the `height` in options when creating the table, and then calling `Tabulator.prototype.setHeight()` when the window resize event is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

The best workaround I found:

- set `height: 'auto'` in options when initializing Tabulator
- use the following CSS:

```css
.tabulator-max-vh-50 .tabulator-tableHolder { 
  max-height: 50vh !important;
  height: auto !important;
  min-height: auto !important;
}
```

I know it's not a good practise to use `!important`, but I needed it to override the styles that are set when Tabulator calls its function `RowManager.prototype.adjustTableSize()`

[JSFiddle with example](https://jsfiddle.net/dannyvop/3fkeam7y/17/)

Note:
When the `height` property is not given in the options when initializing Tabulator, then even when `virtualDom:true`, the table is rendered in classic mode, which then has this unwanted behaviour of frozen column moving for a fraction of a second.
However, the `height` property doesn't have to be a number in px, so I used `'auto'` which is valid CSS value for this property and it works ok.